Stuck at 1 training cell in Notebook Instance in AWS SageMaker
I have started running a command to train a model using Ultralytics YOLOv8.2.4.
Most of the prerequisites should have already been installed. However whenever i run the cell, it will get stuck at the following:
Starting training for 100 epochs...

      Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
  0%|          | 0/143 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

After which it will get stuck there for hours with nothing changing and the cell stops running.
There was once i stopped the notebook and tried to restart, and i got the following error message:
IOStream.flush timed out

Does anyone knows what is the issue?
My current Jupyter Notebook instance is currently running at ml.t3.medium
I have tried to restart the notebook instance but does not seems to start training. Have also tried on google colab and it works fine.

If you need a GPU, ml.t3.medium does not have any GPUs. ml.g4*, ml.g5* have GPUs for example.
